# Fetching data in one query from mapping table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, performance, optimization

I want to fetch the data from following tables such that i do not have to call multiple queries and set the attribute of response *isLikedByUser*. *userId* i am sending in the request.

Posts -- Table Name
userId,
postId,
text,
likesCount,
commentsCount

LikeMapping -- Table Name
userId,
postid

Now I wrote query and fetched data from first table based on *userId*. Then iterated on each row and for each *postId* and *userId* from request found rows in Table 2 and if data is found I set the attribute of *isLikedByUser*.

How can I write the query which can help me to fill the attribute value without writing query in loop.

Thanks

To clarify more *isLikedByUser* is only the response attribute no column in any table and want to set it as true or false if mapping is found in second table.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but it sounds like you could perform an INNER JOIN. Select * from Posts p INNER JOIN LikeMapping lm ON p.postId = lm.postId WHERE lm.userId = userIdFromRequest

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: Could you share some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: No Derek, its not simple join what i was asking for. I want to set one of the response attribute value based on data if available in mapping table. (second). I achieved it by iterating through the data found from first table but i want to do it in one query.

Comment: For example. i called the RestAPI with userId 100 and queried the Posts table for the posts given by user 100.

Posts  
1, 100, xxx, yyy, zzz
2, 102, aaa, bbb, ccc
3, 101, sss, fff, ggg
4, 100, uuu, nnn, mmm

Only two rows for the first query as user did only two posts (1,4)

LikeMapping
1,105
2,103
3,106
4,100
Now for each postId (1,4) done by user if there is data in mapping table where postId=1 and userId =100
set the response attribute isLikedByUser = true. That is i want to figure out if the user has liked his own post or not as posts likes is maintained in mapping table.

Comment: If you think the information you just entered is relevant to your question then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55106681/edit) the question instead of posting it as comments

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `CASE` statement. Something like below should work.

```
Select  p.*,
        case count(lm.postid) when 0 then true else false end as isLikedByUser
    from  Posts p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  LikeMapping lm  ON p.postId = lm.postId
    WHERE  lm.userId = userIdFromRequest
    group by  userId, postId, text, likesCount, commentsCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a LEFT JOIN on a sub-query together with COALESCE to get a true/false (1/0) flag if the user has liked own post or not for each post by the given user

```
SELECT p.*, COALESCE(isLikedByUSer, 0)
FROM Posts p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 1 isLikedByUser, postId, userID FROM LikeMapping) as l ON l.postId = p.postId AND l.userId = p.userId
WHERE p.userId = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be faster than the other Answers.

```
SELECT p.*,
       lm.postid IS NOT NULL AS isLikedByUser
    FROM Posts AS p
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT postid FROM LikeMapping ) AS lm
          ON lm.postid = p.postid
```

What version of MySQL?  This probably needs 5.6 or later.

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` if you wish to discuss further.